# Why is $\frac {4\sqrt{40}}{\log_{10}{40}} - 4\sqrt{10}$ so close to $\pi$?

Tags: pi

Why is $$\frac {4\sqrt{40}}{\log_{10}{40}} - 4\sqrt{10}\approx 3.1419$$ so close to $\pi$?

Comment: It is a coindent

Comment: Something out there's gotta be close to $\pi$, right?

Comment: For the same reason $\,0.333301\,$ is so close to $\;\frac13\;$ : *because*.

Comment: This also $(\ln 6)^{(\ln 5)^{(\ln 4)^{(\ln 3)^{(\ln 2)}}}}$

Comment: You're multiplying the square root of $10$ by a number slightly smaller than $1$, so not a big surprise.

Comment: Why is 3.1415 so close to $\pi$? Note that it _closer_ than your example, despite being _shorter_.

Comment: You may find the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_coincidence#Concerning_powers_of_.CF.80 interesting.

Comment: Alright, I just though there may have been an interesting reason.

Answer (score 2):

Just the same way as $\sqrt{10}, \frac{22}{7}$ are close to $\pi$.

Comment: $\frac{22}{7}$ is a bit more special being a convergent to $\pi$.

Comment: @snulty Why? 10 is a convergent of $\pi^2$, which leads to $\pi \approx \sqrt{10}$

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont I think you're missing my point, $\frac{22}{7}$ being rational, and a convergent in the sense of continued fractions, means that it's the closest approximation by a rational, given that the denominator is allowed to be no bigger than seven. I mean you could concoct all sorts of irrationals that approximate $\pi$.

Comment: @snulty The first convergents of $\pi$ are $3$ and $\frac{22}{7}$, and the first two convergents of $\pi^2$ are $9$ and $10$. 

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued+fraction+pi%5E2

Taking the root at both sides of $\pi^2 \approx 9$ gives $\pi \approx 3$, while taking the square root at both sides of $\pi^2 \approx 10$ gives $\pi \approx \sqrt{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

You know $\pi\approx 3.141592$. The interval $[a,b]$ where $a=3.141591$ and $b=3.141593$ contains uncountable many numbers (rational, algebraic and trascendental ones) close to $\pi$. Anyway, to find out closed forms for $\pi$ is a matter of contemporary research and, for instance the number$$\frac{\ln(640320^3+744)}{\sqrt{163}}$$ gives $30$ exact decimal digits of approximation. The number will be much more valuable the greater the approximation be and the number above is not easy to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

By combining up to 15 mathematical symbols from the dozens available, you can make trillions of numbers. Some of them will be close to $\pi$, including $3.1416$, which requires only 6 symbols.